# GCP NATS Subscriber/Workers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nats.io

Currently we are using Cloud Run for our API, Cloud Tasks & Scheduler for background and scheduled tasks.

We want to move away from Cloud Tasks & Scheduler and have been looking at NATS with FastStream (https://github.com/airtai/faststream), so we are not tied to GCP anymore and we can easily move all our services to Scaleway for example, where our DB is hosted.

The nice thing that using Cloud Tasks/Scheduler has is that it auto scales the services when tasks ramp up.

So the questions are:

- When using NATS and deploying the Worker services through Cloud Run (always on, min 1 instance), will and how will the service auto scale?
- Should we go with Compute Engine for this, or why not?
- What other options do we have (with auto scaling), instead of using k8s?

Thanks in advance.